# xindy no lettergroup in the index

Tags: xindy

I am using a normal English index with `xindy`, but I would like to get rid of the Lettergroups at the beginnings of the each group. I was able to work with `.ist` before, but it does not work with `xindy`, and searching online I have not found the way to sort it out.

I understand that I have to write a simple `.xdy` file, but what sort of macro should I put in?

I have not done any change to the Index, and the index is simply in English. This is the reason for the absence of a MWE.

Comment: There might be a much easier method. The letter groups are typeset using a macro (you can look in the `.ind` file for the name. If I remember correctly it is defined using providecommand in the index. Thus if that same macro is redefined in the preamble to do nothing except taking an argument, then the letter groups disappear.

Comment: @daleif, thanks, you directed on the right path, I believe, I am now trying to see if I am able to work with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

B\index{Bbb}
X\index{Xxx}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Xindy then generates the following `.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{B}
  \item Bbb, 1

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{X}
  \item Xxx, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Thus if we add the following to the preamble, the letter groups disappear:

```
\providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{}
```

(because `\providecommand` only defines a macro if it does not already exist)

Comment: I just put into my file, just before the \makeindex command, and it works perfectly

Comment: Is it posible to do this running `xindy` with a suitable style file `.xdy`? `texindy -M nolettergroupstyle ...`

Comment: @skpblack sure, the syntax is just vastly different than a normal `.ist` file for `makeindex`. Try running `xindy --help`, `texindy` is just a call to `xindy` with a special `xdy`

Answer (score 3):

You can make a simple `no-lg.xdy`:

`(define-letter-groups (""))`

and run

`xindy -M no-lg ...`

This will make just one

`\lettergroup{}`

in the beginning of you `.ind` file.